# SSRS reports and CRM marketing list

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm

I have started creating more and more reports in SSRS now. Reports that are not possible in native CRM (either advance find or reporting). While most are for data analysis, few are for finding our top customer by shop and month/year.

Problem is that the SSRS gives me very accurate and nice report of top 100 spenders but I can't use that in marketing these contacts. I am not sure if there is any way to bring this contacts from the result in to crm and use it to create a marketing list.

I will be very grateful if anyone know the way to bring ssrs report result in to CRM. (not creating new report using import report wizard) even it means creating a new plugin etc.

CRM 2011
Rollout 11
on premise
SQL server 2012

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to upload your report to crm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an application that will execute the same `SQL` query to find the top 100 spenders and create the marketing list and add the members by code.

Unfortunately there isn't a direct way to create a marketing list starting from a report or similar.

Comment: this application, its not is FetchXML by any chance? I am learning C# at the moment. Mainly to basic CRM plugins. if possible can you please give me a little push by telling me which language is best to write this application?

Comment: you can write this application using C#, if your query is written with FetchXml is the same: execute the fetchxml, retrieve the results and create the marketing list by code.